# Can't get async method to work: "The Connection is closed"

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, task

I'm trying to asynchronously delete records of photos that aren't needed anymore, and I just cannot get this method to work. I keep getting an exception:

> Invalid operation. The connection is closed.

The trouble seems to be with the `foreach` loop... If I do all this for a single photo instead of for all of them, then it works. For example, if the array of photos I send this method has exactly 1 member, then it works. If there are two, then it fails.

But if I duplicate pieces of the code to hardcode processing the first photo of the array and the second photo of the array etc, it works. It's just when I use an actual loop that it explodes. What the hell.

```cs
public async void DeletePhotosAsync(PhotoEntity[] photos)
{
    var deletingParentPhotos = new List<Task>();
    var deletingChildPhotos = new List<Task>();
    try
    {
        _siteAdapter.StartTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted, "Delete Photos");

        foreach (var photo in photos)
        {
            deletingChildPhotos.Add(Task.Run(() => _siteAdapter.DeleteEntityCollection(photo.Photo.ChildPhotos)));
        }

        await Task.WhenAll(deletingChildPhotos).ConfigureAwait(false);

        foreach (var photo in photos)
        {
            deletingParentPhotos.Add(Task.Run(() => _siteAdapter.DeleteEntity(photo.Photo)));
        }

        await Task.WhenAll(deletingParentPhotos).ConfigureAwait(false);

        _siteAdapter.Commit();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _siteAdapter.Rollback();
    }
}
```

```
at SD.LLBLGen.Pro.ORMSupportClasses.ActionQuery.Execute()
   at SD.LLBLGen.Pro.ORMSupportClasses.DataAccessAdapterCore.ExecuteActionQuery(IActionQuery queryToExecute)
   at SD.LLBLGen.Pro.ORMSupportClasses.DataAccessAdapterCore.DeleteEntity(IEntity2 entityToDelete, IPredicateExpression deleteRestriction)
   at SD.LLBLGen.Pro.ORMSupportClasses.DataAccessAdapterBase.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<DeleteEntity>b__0()
   at SD.LLBLGen.Pro.ORMSupportClasses.UnitOfWork2.HandleDeletes(IDataAccessAdapter adapterToUse)
   at SD.LLBLGen.Pro.ORMSupportClasses.UnitOfWork2.CommitImpl(IDataAccessAdapter adapterToUse, Boolean autoCommit)
   at SD.LLBLGen.Pro.ORMSupportClasses.DataAccessAdapterCore.DeleteEntityCollection(IEntityCollection2 collectionToDelete)
   at SD.LLBLGen.Pro.ORMSupportClasses.DataAccessAdapterBase.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<DeleteEntityCollection>b__0()
   at Site.Models.PhotoModel.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.<DeleteInspectionPhotosAsync>b__0() in C:\Users\aletwor\source\repos\Site\Site.Models\PhotoModel.cs:line 158
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Site.Models.PhotoModel.<DeleteInspectionPhotosAsync>d__9.MoveNext() in C:\Users\aletwor\source\repos\Site\Site.Models\PhotoModel.cs:line 174
```

Comment: What is `_siteAdapter`? Seeing that it's not declared in this method, I suspect you are reusing it? That would likely be the problem.

Comment: I agree with Gabriel. I think that a [mcve] would help here immensely. The code you've posted is irrelevant.

Comment: Firstly, this is an `async void` (not your problem but doesn't look very good). Secondly, it looks like you are using a database in several threads, which is usually the wrong approach, you are also caching a db connection, which is usually a sign that something is wrong, and all of this looks very thread unsafe

Comment: Imagine you handed a worker a note that said "please make the beds in rooms 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 and 10, and whatever you do, *do not tell me when you're done*".  Figuring that the beds are all made, you then blow up the hotel at a random time, and are surprised to discover that the worker failed to make some of the beds before the hotel was demolished and is now complaining. How do you avoid this situation? By not doing what you did. **Do not hire a worker; do the I/O bound work yourself on the current thread. Predicate closing the connection on all pending tasks being complete**.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you're using `Task.Run` which kicks off an asynchronous task that you're not waiting on. These tasks can run *after* you commit/rollback the `_siteAdapter` transaction.

To do this properly you need to wait on all those tasks. It may also be possible that running them in parallel on background threads doesn't give any benefit, depending upon what `DeleteEntity` and `DeleteEntityCollection` are actually doing.